# rav wosner and the kind kallah who got a brocho

Tags: rabbis, wedding, agada-stories-legends, chesed-kindness

a couple of years ago I read a very moving story of a Kalloh who insisted that she doesn't break her engagement in spite of the situation which had arisen. 
The story of the Kalloh moved Harav Shmuel Wosner and he gave her a brocho.
I don't remember the details, but the story was well covered at the time.
does anyone remember such a scene?!

Comment: A. The question is completely unclear. There are almost no details to start with - just 1.Kallah 2.R' Wosner and 3.Berachah. B. The answer(s) given have details completely contrary to one of the (very, very) few details in the question - who gave whom the Berachah. C. Guessing game. (D. Close.)

Answer (score 8):

One source for the story you mentioned:

http://yeranenyaakov.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/rav-wosner-asks-kallah-for-blessing.html

In short, the author relates how a young woman received a wonderful shidduch. However, the chatan became ill and the local beit din advised that the couple not go forward. the kallah wrote to R' Wosner, who said that although he had not presided over a case in some time, he would chair his bada"tz in such a case.

R' Wosner asked the kallah whether she wished to go forward; her response is and the rest of the article is quoted here:

> The Kallah replied, "If so, I want to go on with the Shidduch. Rav Wosner, please give us a Beracha that the Shidduch should be successful and that the Hatan should have length of days, and that he will be healthy from now on."
>
> When Rav Wosner heard the Kallah's words, he broke out crying, and after a few long minutes that seemed to everyone like an eternity, Rav Wosner said, "This Kallah does not need my Beracha after such an act of courage. I don't need to bless you - rather, I request that you bless me that I should have length of days and continue to disseminate Torah."

Comment: Despite "rabbi"'s duplicate answer, this does not answer the question asked. (Not your fault, really; it's a terrible question, at least for our format.)  Good for you, at least, for deciphering what he was talking about.

Comment: Does anyone know what happened to the chosson?